# How to use a bash script to repeatedly feed a string into a program?

Tags: c, bash

I have a program that receives input through stdin.
It's something like "1 10".

What I want to do is a script that gives the "1 10" string thousands of times, because I need to make sure the program doesn't fail with big quantities of data.

I can't seem to be able to do this... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you've got the program, then `yes "1 10"` does the job for an indefinite number of iterations (until you interrupt it, or the process it feeds exits, or …).  If you want varying input, life is more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop in bash, and pipe the result to your program:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do 
    echo "My input"
done | ./my_program
```

Or as one line which can be used directly from the command line:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do echo "My input"; done | ./my_program
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an endless loop:

```
while :; do echo "1 10"; done | consumer
```

Or a less aggressive version:

```
while sleep 1; do echo "1 10"; done | consumer
```

Answer (score 1):

`yes` does that.

```
$: yes 1 10 | head
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
1 10
```

So for an infinite input,

```
yes 1 10 | myProg
```

Or if you want a limit,

```
yes 1 10 | head -99999 | myProg
```

Comment: And *NOW* I see that  Jonathan Leffler  offered that solution as a comment two hours ago, lol...

Comment: On a Mac, I needed the quotes around the '1 10' — the macOS or BSD variant of `yes` only echoes its first argument.  When I use GNU `yes`, the quotes aren't needed; it echoes all its arguments on each line with spaces separating them.  Just another tiny difference.  The GNU processing is sensible.